# What Alternatives are there to Toilet Wax Rings?

Tags: toilet

I've got a toilet to set, on a flush but rough and older metal flange.

What alternatives are there to toilet wax rings?  I've tried two over time, each subsequently became destroyed when the toilet needed to be snaked.

Answer (score 1):

First off, can you replace the old rough flange or add a 1/4" extension plate to smooth it out? If not, can you file it down a bit and smooth out the rough spots? I've used a number of the seals pictured below and have much more luck with them than with the wax rings. Good luck

[image]

Comment: Yea, that's the exact ring I used before.  It ended up a urine and feces soaked mess.  That's not only the most expensive of the locally available wax alternatives, but it's made of open cell foam that if the green coating is nicked, soaks up water.  A hazard to your floors.

Comment: @Bryce Then you should have included that in your question. You asked for an alternative to wax rings.